# Execute batch file with args in java

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

I am trying to run batch file using java command.
I have following code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\filecompare.bat");
```

I have batch file named filecompare.bat as below

```
fc "C:\temp\Sept_2016\22Sept\MSP_Files\msp.txt" "C:\temp\Sept_2016\22Sept\MIB_Files\mib.txt">>"C:\temp\Sept_2016\22Sept\mismatch.txt"
```

This works as per expected and output gets stored in txt file.

Now I don't want to use hard coded values as above I want to get the values from Java program. So I am writing java code as below

```
String file1 = new String("C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\MSP_Files\\msp.txt");
String file2 = new String("C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\MIB_Files\\mib.txt");
String file3 = new String("C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\mismatch.txt");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\filecompare.bat", file1, file2, file3});
```

On the similar lines I am modifying batch file as

```
fc %4 %5>>%6
```

But this does not seem to be working. It is just opening dos window.

Could you please help me achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You passing only 3 parameters why you use `%4`, `%5` and `%6`?

Comment: I am passing 5 parameters as below
1) "cmd.exe", 
2) "/c", 
3) "start C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\filecompare.bat", 
4) file1, 
5) file2, 
6) file3

Comment: I belive that first three elements of your String[] should be concatenated. And by the way, why can't you just concatanate all the string and just pass a single String?

Comment: You have combined two parameters which can cause problems: `start` and `C:\\temp\\Sept_2016\\22Sept\\filecompare.bat`. Anyway `start` is not needed you can remove it.

Comment: @Sachin, You are only passing 3 arguments to the batch file!

Comment: @Sachin Yes. You passing 5 parameters to `cmd` but when it invokes `filecompare.bat` it pass only 3 parameters there. `filecompare.bat` know nothing about  those 5 parameters. It knows only about parameters that was passed to it.

Comment: Ok so If I modify my batch file as fc %1 %2>>%3 it shoud work right?

Comment: Why are you using `start` after all?

Comment: Hey guys thanks a lot. It is working now.
The only problem I can see now is that it is opening 2 command prompts.
Any thought on that?

Comment: This is no different then any other scripting language I have ever used. The number of parameters you pass starts after the script you are executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `fc %4 %5>>%6` with `fc %1 %2>>%3`.

`filecompare.bat` being executed only aware of its own parameter, not parameters you pass to `cmd`.

Comment: Hey Talex, thanks man. Thanks a lot. It is working now. The only problem I can see now is that it is opening 2 command prompts. Any thought on that?

Comment: As it was suggested remove `start` from parameters.

Comment: Removed start but then it is opening a single command prompt but it is not processing my command, it simply opens single command prompt

Comment: Post it as another question.

Comment: My problem got solved.
Actually there was another pience of code which was opening another command prompt.
I removed that code and now it is working as expected.
Just one note to all guys. Start is needed to open up command prompt If I remove start then it does not open the command prompt.

Comment: @Sachin, `start` opens a new `cmd` window, but it does not wait until the started thing is finished executing, unless you provide the `/WAIT` option...